# Glide и Bitmap сохраняет два одинаковых изображения

Tags: java, android, bitmap, glide

Имеется адаптер, код представлен ниже. Логика работы такая: на вход адаптера поступает массив из имён файлов, обычно 6-9 имён файлов. В адаптере идёт проверка наличия такого файла в папке уменьшенных изображений. Если такого файла нет, то Glide + Bitmap создают уменьшенную копию этого изображения из оригинала в папку уменьшенных изображений. Всё работает нормально, все файлы создаются, всё отображается. Но есть одна проблема - практически всегда создаётся два одинаковых изображения. Не могу понять причину и соответственно решить возникшую проблему. Прошу помочь.

```
private class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context context;
    List<String> objects;
    String foto_url;
    ImageView imageView;

    private ImageAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects)
        {
        super(context, R.layout.gallery_content_image, objects);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
        }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
        {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_content_image, parent, false);
            }

        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        foto_url = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Images/Mini/" + getItem(position);

        File dir = new File(foto_url);
        if (!dir.isFile())
            {
            Glide.with(context).load((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Images/Original/" + getItem(position))).asBitmap().override(100, 100).centerCrop().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>()
                {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation glideAnimation)
                    {
                    File file = new File(foto_url);
                    FileOutputStream out;
                    try {
                        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, out);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        out.close();
                        }
                    catch (IOException e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        else
            {
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(foto_url));
            }

        return view;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. Glide создает миниатюру не моментально, метод getView может быть вызван несколько раз, до того как файл с миниатюрой будет создан

```
...    
File fotoFile = new File(foto_url);
if (!fotoFile.exist()) {
    fotoFile.createNewFile();
    Glide.with(context).....
} else {
    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(foto_url));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось. Правда не все изображения сразу отображаются, но видимо это другая тема. А есть ли вообще смысл создавать миниатюры, если Glide сам их создаёт в кеше?